# How to plot a list of data frames in one plot super-imposed

Tags: r, list, plot, time-series

Things I wanted to do:

1. create a plot of all this days without rain in my list of lists "weekdays",     plotted super-imposed. (One scatterplot of points with one x and y axis)
2. plot an averaged curve representing the hydrograph of all weekdays with no rain in the observed time!

This is my final solution (the code is much too complicated I think, but it works:

```
#create list of data frames splitted by days
daysplit<-split.default(data_regression_PCM4 [,1], format(index(data_regression_PCM4), "%a"))


#create a list for each day of the week
Monday<-list(daysplit$Mo)

#create a list "Monday" splitted by date
Monday<-as.data.frame(Monday)
Monday [,2]<-row.names(Monday)
Monday[,2]<-as.POSIXct(Monday[,2], format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tz="UTC")
Monday <- xts(Monday[,-2], order.by=Monday[,2])
Monday<-split(Monday, "days")

#Monday without rain (flow rate less than 20 L/s)
cond <- lapply(Monday, function(x) max(x) < 20)
Monday_TW<-Monday[unlist(cond)] #Monday "No rain"

#convert lists of xts to lists of df
Monday_TW <- lapply(Monday_TW, function(x) data.frame(DateTime=index(x),Abfluss=coredata(x)))

#Extract lists to data frames while omitting the DateTime column
mo<-lapply(Monday_TW, function(x) x[!(names(x) %in% c("DateTime"))])
mo <- do.call(cbind,mo)

#combine all weekdays to one df
weekdays_TW<-cbind(mo,di,mi,do,fr)
weekdays_TW [,11]<-(seq(as.POSIXct("2014-12-29 00:00:00",tz="UTC"), as.POSIXct("2014-12-29 23:55:00",tz="UTC"),by="5 min"))#add Time column with random date (only time matters)
names(weekdays_TW)<-c("Abfluss_1","Abfluss_2","Abfluss_3","Abfluss_4","Abfluss_5","Abfluss_6","Abfluss_7","Abfluss_8","Abfluss_9","Abfluss_10","Time")
weekdays_TW<-weekdays_TW[c(11,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)]

#melt df
melted_TW <- melt(weekdays_TW ,  id = 'Time', value_name = 'series')
names(melted_TW)<-c("Time","values","Abfluss")

##Plot via ggplot2
TW_plot<-ggplot(melted_TW, aes(Time,Abfluss)) + geom_point(aes(color = values))
TW_plot+stat_smooth(method = "lm", formula = y ~ poly(x, 9), size = 1,se=F)+
scale_x_datetime( breaks=("2 hour"),minor_breaks=("1 hour"),labels=date_format("%H:%M"))  +  
xlab("Time [h]")+ ylab("Abfluss Q [L/s]")   + 
"Montag_2", "Dienstag_1", "Dienstag_2","Mittwoch_1","Mittwoch_2","Donnerstag_1","Donnerstag_2","Freitag_1","Freitag_2"))+ labs(title="Tagesgang PCM4 / Wochentage") +
theme(plot.title = element_text(lineheight=.8, face="bold"))
```

Resulting plot:

[image]

And this is a sample of the data I used:

```
DateTime            Q (L/s)
2015-01-26 00:00:00 12.057333
2015-01-26 00:15:00 13.137333
2015-01-26 00:30:00 12.639000
2015-01-26 00:45:00 12.476333
```

This is the dataset I used:

http://m.uploadedit.com/ba3d/1432744791634.TXT

If someone happens to find a simpler solution, I would appreciate that!

Comment: Sadly this one does not work. For "Weekdays" as object it does not work at all and returns the error : `Error in xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : 
  'x' is a list, but does not have components 'x' and 'y'`  ;If I just use e.g. "Monday_TW" ,it says: "add is no graphic parameter" and only plots the first graph of the list.

Comment: does not seem to work either :(     `Error in x[, 1] : incorrect number of dimensions`

Comment: The link is just fine, thanks.

Comment: Found a solution, that worked for me!! Thanks for your effort :)

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: I had a data frame of daily values. I wanted to plot the daily wastewater-flow of all weekdays within the range of my data superimposed in one plot and add a smoothed average curve to this plot!